# Struts2 with JS

Tags: javascript, struts2

I am new to Json and Struts2. I want to make the 2nd dropdown value based on 1st but i am not getting anything back even the alert inside the getjson is also not coming. I need statelist data so i can populate the statelist based on country

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
        <struts>
            <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
            <package name="basicstruts2" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">    
                <action name="changeStateName" class="ActionController.changeStateName" method="getStateName">
                </action>
            </package>
        </struts>
```

JSP Page

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#countrylist").change(function changeState(){
                var country=$( "#countrylist option:selected" ).text();
                alert("inside function"+country);

                $.getJSON('changeStateName.action?country='+country,
                        function(data){   
alert("inside getjson"+country);
                     var options = $("#StateList");
                     options.find('option')
                     .remove()
                     .end();
                     options.append($("<option />").val("-1").text("--Select State--"));
                    $.each(divisionList, function() {

                         options.append($("<option />").val(this).text(this));
                     }); 

                });
                 });

        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Welcome file <s:property value="userName"/></h1>

        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
         <tbody>

           <tr><td><s:select id="countrylist" list="cuntry" key="CountryName" ></s:select></td></tr>

           <tr><td><s:select id="StateList" list="state" key="StateName" headerKey="0" headerValue="--select--"></s:select></td></tr>

           <tr><td><s:submit></s:submit></td></tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Action Class

```
        public class changeStateName {
        private HashMap<String,String> stateList=new HashMap<String,String>();

            public HashMap<String, String> getStateList() {
                return stateList;
            }
            public void setStateList(HashMap<String, String> stateList) {
                this.stateList = stateList;
            }
        public HashMap<String, String> getStateName() throws IOException{
                System.out.println("inside changeStateName"+country);
                HashMap<String,String> sl=new HashMap<String, String>();
                sl.put("1", "kar");
                sl.put("2", "Del");
                sl.put("3", "Har");
                setStateList(sl);
                return stateList;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I suggest you to learn the basics of S2. Take a look at http://struts.apache.org/docs/tutorials.html.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see,you dont have country variable in changeStateName class.your getStateName() method should return string.

```
  public String getStateName() throws IOException{

            // Buisness logic here

            return "success"; //hoping everything works fine :-)
        }
```

your Struts.xml file pretty messy plus,
for JSON you have to extend json-default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
    <struts>
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
        <package name="basicstruts2" namespace="/" extends="json-default">    
            <action name="changeStateName" class="ActionController.changeStateName" method="getStateName">
                 <result name="success" type="json" />
            </action>
        </package>
    </struts>
```

check complete demo here.
http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/ajax-implementation-in-struts-2-using-jquery-and-json/

I hope this works fine!!!

Comment: Govi ,Thanks for ur response . Actually that was a jar issue so checked the jar on what u have given the on that url. I added same jar now its working fine

Comment: if you found my answer useful, don't bother to select it as answer :-)